# Visual Studio 2013 IIS web site - problems with JS files

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, chart.js

I am fighting this problem for almost a week. After googleing it a lot I decide to put here exactly what is my problem to see if someone can provide some light.

I am developing a website application using google chart. I am developing it with Visual Studio 2013 in ASP .NET. The application is published in IIS 8.5. The weird thing is that it was working fine until last week when I had do perform a server restart. After restarting it the application seems to be no able to load the JS API (not just google chart but any JS, including JQuery).

If I copy a google chart example (plain html with JS inside it) and open in Chrome it works so the javascript api is loading. The problem happen just when I try to run it from inside VS Studio (the erro message is [0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'google' is undefined] or try to publish it.

Could it be some kind of network policie blocking it? How can I check it?

Here is the head of the default.aspx file

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    .auto-style1 {
        font-size: xx-large;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar', 'table', 'controls']});
</script> 

<script src="GraphsAndTables.js"></script>
<script>google.setOnLoadCallback(DrawAll);</script>
```

As you can see the src are correct (I double check it and it loads in plain htlm).

I change the position of google.load() but it still giving the same erro.

[image]

Comment: I did that but it did not worked. It continues to give the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using old library loader code you need to update your loader code or load both the old library loader and the new library loader.

> **Limitations**: For `Geochart` and `Map Chart`, you must load both the old library loader
>   and the new library loader.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
```

Your code should look like below

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>// Old Library Loader
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['corechart', 'bar', 'table', 'controls'] });
</script>
```

Check Google documntation to [Update Library Loader Code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#update-library-loader-code)

Comment: Hi Wael. Thank you very much. There is nothing better than an external view to catch a silly error like that!